# Setting cell.textlabel.text from json array

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview, ios6, nsarray

Hello I'm trying to parse data from json and get the values to show in cells.

Here is my ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;
    NSMutableData *data;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *category;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *coursesArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *parsedData;

@end
```

This is what I have in ViewController.m

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    coursesArray = [parsedData valueForKey:@"courses"];
    NSLog(@"coursesArray: %@", coursesArray);
    category = [coursesArray valueForKey:@"category"];
    NSLog(@"%@", category);
}
-(int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [category objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSLog(@"%@", category);
    return cell;
}
```

At connectionDidFinishLoading I see in the log the right values, but when I try to check them before the cell is created I get null.
What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call

```
 [mainTableView reloadData];
```

inside your `-connectionDidFinishLoading:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your category  array is not released/autoreleased.